# How to get the class from an instantiation in JS?

Tags: javascript, class

If I have a JavaScript class like this:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor() {}
}
```

I can instantiate it using:

```js
const myFoo = new Foo();
```

But say I have a function that takes a class instantiation like `myFoo` as a parameter. How can I access `Foo` to modify it?

Comment: You cannot modify the class itself. How should that work?

Comment: You can access the constructor function by the `constructor` property on the instance, eg `myFoo.constructor`

Comment: *Why* would you need to do this? Class definitions aren't generally meant to be modified in this way, and could cause serious problems later on.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff JavaScript is a prototype-based language. And you can do changes to a class, like removing, adding, or changing functions.

Comment: What modification do you want to do to that class and why?

Comment: so, you want to mess with `myFoo.constructor.prototype`?

Comment: _"How can I access Foo to modify it?"_ - are you trying to mutate the `myFoo` object? If yes, then you can create a method inside the `Foo` class and then call that method using the `myFoo` instance. Example: `myFoo.setName("some name")`

Comment: If you think that the answers to the duplicate question do not answer your question, you need to explicitly say why this is the case.